# Dos atributos no persisten en un JSON

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con Angular 6 y Cloud Firestore, que consiste en agregar productos. He definido una interfaz con los atributos que deberá de llevar, y al momento de recibirlos de un formulario, los manejo con el servicio:

```
addProduct(idDepartament: string, product: Product, image: File) {
    const id = this.db.createId();
    const document = this.db.doc(`departaments/${idDepartament}/products/${id}`);
    // Aquí sí presiste el ID del producto
    product.id = id;

    if (image) {
      // Si existe la imagen, entonces la guardará en Firebase Storage
      const path = `images/${idDepartament}/${id}/${image.name}`;
      const ref = this.storage.ref(path);
      const task = this.storage.upload(path, image);
      task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          ref.getDownloadURL().subscribe((data: string) => {
            product.image = data; // Guarda la dirección donde se almacenó la imagen
            product.nameImage = image.name; // Guarda el nombre de la imagen
          });
        })).subscribe();
    } else {
      // Si no hay imagen, tendrá una por defecto
      product.image = './assets/img/noImage.png';
    }

    // Retorna una promesa para mostrar si todo salió bien, o hubo un problema en la subida del archivo
    return document.set(product);
  }
```

Me parece que todo está bien, sin embargo, al probarlo no guarda `nameImage` ni `image` en `product`. Y verifiqué que sí aparezcan en el objecto:
[Objecto product](http://prntscr.com/khyjfy)

[image: Objeto product]

¿Qué sucede? Parece que lo está guardando correctamente. No obstante, en la Base de Datos no se encuentran los dos atributos para la imagen:
[Archivo en Firebase](http://prntscr.com/khyl8s)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias. Espero me puedan aclarar este suceso tan extraño, pues hace un par de días funcionaba bien, y ahora ya no quiere almacenar esos dos atributos.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas realizando trabajos asíncronos y para cuando hagas `document.set(product)` la imagen aun no se ha guardado en la base de datos.

Necesitas esperar a que la imagen se guarde completamente, para que se ejecute el código en el que `image` y `nameImage` se guardan y entonces (y solo entonces) vas a tener listo todo para guardar.

Una solución posible (de muchas) sería la siguiente:

```
addProduct(idDepartament: string, product: Product, image: File) {
   const id = this.db.createId();
   const document = this.db.doc(`departaments/${idDepartament}/products/${id}`);
   product.id = id;

  // Preparamos una Promesa para cuando se termine el trabajo con la imagen
  const p = new Promise<Product>((resolve, reject) => {
     if (image) {
        // Si existe la imagen, entonces la guardará en Firebase Storage
        const path = `images/${idDepartament}/${id}/${image.name}`;
        const ref = this.storage.ref(path);
        const task = this.storage.upload(path, image);
        task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
          // finalize no se ejecutará sino hasta que se guarde la imagen
          finalize(() => {
            ref.getDownloadURL().subscribe((data: string) => {
              product.image = data; 
              product.nameImage = image.name; 
              // Resolver la promesa con el producto actualizado
              resolve(product);
            });
          })).subscribe();
      } else {
        // Si no hay imagen, tendrá una por defecto
        product.image = './assets/img/noImage.png';
        // Resolver la promesa con el producto actualizado
        resolve(product);
      }
   });

   // Esperamos que se resuelva la promesa anterior
   return p.then((resultProduct) => {
      // Retorna una promesa para mostrar si todo salió bien, o hubo un problema en la subida del archivo
      return document.set(resultProduct);
   });
}
```

Comment: Tienes razón, implementé una Promesa y ya me resuelve correctamente la persistencia. ¿Cuáles podrían ser las otras formas que mencionas?

Comment: No fijate, no se me ocurre ninguna otra forma, por lo menos ninguna otra que sea tan eficiente ;)